# Android Studio: porting old example fails at System.loadLibrary("muse_android");

Tags: android, loadlibrary

(again a day wasted..)
I can compile and run a 2016 example with updating build.gradle to

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.muserobo"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 30
```

But when i copy the code into a new project (File->new->New_Project->Empty_Activity), the project compiles successfully but the code

```
try {
    System.loadLibrary("muse_android");
} catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError var1) {
    Log.v("MUSE", "Failed to load libmuse_android.so. Make sure the jni symbols are accessible somehow.");
}
```

fails :-( Yes i copied the files `libmuse_android.so` to `app\src\main\jniLibs\armeabi-v7a` and `libmuse_android.jar` to `app\libs` .

I can delete these files in the updated example by right clicking on them in the project-tree and selecting delete in the context menu. When i then manually copy the files back in place with the windows file explorer (as i did with new project), the example code runs again successfully.

So i am missing some hidden option somewhere that will make the code find that library at runtime or add it to the apk while compiling :-(
In other words, simply copying the two files to their destinations is not enough :-/

Here the build.gradle of the new project:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.muserobo"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

**Please help save my day :-)**

Answer (score 2):

Another half of a day wasted on shitty Android.
The library `libmuse_android.so` indeed was packed into the `app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk`  file with *Build->Rebuild_Project* but was **NOT** packed into that same apk when choosing *Run->Debug_'app'*

Solution: *Run->Edit_Configuration->app->Depoly:* `"Default APK"` -> `"APK from app bundle"`

Then an apk that contains the .so is built at `app\build\intermediates\extracted_apks\debug\outbase-armeabi_v7a_2.apk` and now debugging on my Pixel 1 XL can continue :-)

Shitty Android :-(

Comment: hi can you share your  projcet ,im struggling to connect muse still in three days im getting assert error

Comment: I do not really want to publish the code to my GitHub. And don't have the time at the moment to test compilation with my current android studio. Old projects files won't really help you because auf shitty Android .. be aware that the old lib only connects to Muse 1.

Comment: thanks for the reply im useing muse 2 ,i found a way to connect to muse 2 with bluetooth le

Comment: I doubt you succeed accessing raw eeg data. But if you do and want to share do send me an email to roland@robo4future.de and I will make my eegCenter project open source.